# Jquery form submit after prevent default

Tags: jquery, forms, preventdefault

I really stuck on this issue from long time. I am working in Rails application and there is form for creating a business.

Now form should be submit when all the JQuery custom validation passes for that I wrote the below code.

```
$("form#new_business").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var valid = true;
```

var attribute_value = $("input#business_"+to_attribute+"_id").val();

```
if (attribute_value == '') { // means validation fail
  valid = false ;
  flashMessage(to_attribute)
}

if (valid) this.submit();
```

});

now when validation fails it is successfully show the flash message that "attribute can not blank" but when validation passes then not submitting the form the submit button became disable :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$('form#new_business')[0].submit();` instead of `this.submit();` so your code becomes:

```
$("form#new_business").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var valid = true;
  var attribute_value = $("input#business_"+to_attribute+"_id").val();

  if (attribute_value == '') { // means validation fail
    valid = false ;
    flashMessage(to_attribute)
  }

  if (valid) {
    $('form#new_business')[0].submit();
  }
});
```

Comment: this will not work because what happen once validation fail the submit button became disable.

Comment: so enable it before you submit again.  OR, submit the form, not the button